# Python Matlibplot seems not taking input correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a matrix in `matplotlib` whose first column is 100, so I expect the plot to start at 100 on the horizontal axis. However, it somehow start at 0.

Here is my program:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

def ABM(n,m,S0,mu,sigma,dt):
    np.random.seed(999)
    arr = np.zeros((n, m))
    arr[:,0] = S0 #initialize column 0 
    # fill in array entries
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(1, m):
            dW = np.random.normal(0, np.sqrt(dt))
            arr[i,j] = arr[i, j-1] + mu * dt + sigma * dW
    return arr

paths_1 = ABM(n=1000,m=20,S0=100,mu=0,sigma=0.001,dt=1)
print(paths_1)

plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7))

for i in range(n):
    plt.plot(paths_1[i])

plt.title('Simulated Arithmetic Brownian Motion Paths')
plt.xlabel('Time Steps')
plt.ylabel('Stock Price')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Here is my output:

[image: Here is my output]

Can anyone tell me why it is happening and how to fix it please?

Comment: Note that it doesn't really start at 0, you just failed to notice the `+1e2` at the top (which is arguably easy to miss and not a great choice on matplotlib's part in this case). See the answer below on how to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the format of the data, `matplotlib` has decided that your data should be presented in scientific notation, with an offset.

Note the "+1e2" at the top, which indicates the values on the y-axis are to be interpreted as offsets to 1e2, that is 100.

If you don't want that, add the following line:

```
plt.gca().ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, axis='y')
```